# Intuitive meaning of transitive group action.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, soft-question, group-actions

My idea (not read) is that a transitive group action enforces surjective mapping.

The definition of transitive action is that there exists an $x \in X$ such that for any $y \in X$, there exists a $g \in G$ with $g \star x = y.$

$\exists x \in X,\,\forall y\in X, \, \exists g \in G,\, \mid\, g\star x = y$

I want to ask for an example that shows why more than one orbit makes it necessary that transitive group action property is not followed.

Edit : In view of comments by @Qiaochu Yuan, and other want to add:

It's just not the mapping $G \times X \to X$ that transitivity is making surjective, that's always surjective. But transitivity says there exists an $x$ such that the mapping $G \to X$ given by $g \mapsto g \star x$ is surjective. Equivalently, the action has one orbit.

Comment: You seem to be using a rather strange definition of "transitive" [It works but to my mind it is strange.] So you shoudl say exactly how *you* define "orbit".

Comment: I agree that this is a very strange definition of transitive, there's no reason to single out a particular $x \in X$. The more intuitive definition is that for any $x, y \in X$ there exists a $g \in G$ such that $gx = y$; in other words, any two elements of $X$ can be "connected by an element of $G$." So it's like saying that a graph is connected (and one can make this idea precise).

Comment: (I suppose the definition you give has the virtue of correctly specializing to the empty set - which is never transitive - but there are other ways to do this, such as “has exactly $1$ orbit.”)

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Request reference for your statement that : graph of $X$ under transitive group action by group $G$, is connected.

Comment: It's a very straightforward exercise. Take the graph with vertices the elements of $X$ and an edge $x \to y$ for every $g \in G$ such that $gx = y$. The connected components of this graph are exactly the orbits. This is essentially equivalent to the observation about equivalence relations in the beginning of Sourav's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, notice that orbits partition the given set into disjoint subsets. That is, any two orbits are either same or disjoint, and the union of all the orbits is the whole space.

Now, suppose $O_1$ and $O_2$ are two distinct (and hence, disjoint) orbits for the action. That would mean that if we start with any two elements $x \in O_1$ and $y \in O_2$, we cannot find any $g \in G$ such that $g * x = y$. To write in quantifiers, we have

$\forall x \in X, \exists y \in X \text{ such that } \forall g \in G, g * x \neq y$.

This is the definition of an action not being transitive. Also, for every $x \in X$, the element must be in some orbit, and by assumption, there are at least two distinct orbits so that the existence of such a $y$ is also guaranteed.

I hope this answers your question.

---

Edit (Example):

To look at an example illustrating that existence of two more more orbits forces the action not to be transtive, consider the usual action of $SO(2)$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$. From basic linear algebra, we know that this action is precisely rotation of $\mathbb{R}^2$. The orbits in this case are concentric circles. Now, if we take two points on distinct circles, they cannot be brought to each other using rotations, since rotations do not change the length of vectors (and points being on distinct concentric circles require their lengths to be different). I hope you can write the details mathematically for this intuition.

Comment: Request an example.

Comment: I have added some intuition for the example.

Comment: Can there be a simpler example, say of some cyclic or dihedral group on some set. If not, why?

Comment: Well, you can take the trivial action (the one that fixes all points). That would suffice. However, it really does not give much insights.

Comment: Can the notation above be tinkered to get still valid one? Say: $\forall y\in X, \, \exists x \in X,\,\exists g \in G,\, \mid\, g\star x = y$

Comment: You can also look at the action of $O (1) = \left\lbrace \pm 1 \right\rbrace$ on $\mathbb{R}$. This would be a non-trivial action, and yet would be able to give a geometric insight. Also notice that $O (1) = \left\lbrace \pm 1 \right\rbrace \equiv \mathbb{Z}_2$, which is cyclic.

Comment: Yes, the statement which you write is correct. Also, it is trivial since group actions require that the set $X$ be fixed under the action of the identity element $e \in G$. Particularly, in what you write, we can choose $x = y$ and $g = e$, for any action.

Comment: By stating: 'set $X$ be fixed under the action of the identity element $e\in G$', do you mean that $\forall x \in X, \, e\star x=x$ If so, how it ensures ordering of variables in statement above can be tinkered in any order. Had there not be the given property of $e$, then? Say, $e\star x= y$ (hypothetical), then how it forces statement in one way only.

Comment: But the definition of group action requires $e * x = x$ for every $x$.

Comment: Suppose a pseudo action is there.

Comment: Please see my last post on pseudo action, that was mentioned in my last comment too. It was split later in three parts. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4506561/424260

Answer (score 5):

Let us consider a group action of $G$ on a set $X$ defined by $(g, x) =g\star x$

Let $x\in X$ , then orbit of $x$ is defined as $\mathcal{O}_x=\{g\star x:g\in G\}$

Claim:

1. The relation $\sim$ on $X$ defined by $x\sim y\iff \exists g\in G$ such that $y=g\star x$ is an equivalence relation.
2. $[x]=\mathcal{O}_x$
3. $x\sim y\iff y\in \mathcal{O}_x$

---

Claim 2: The following two statements are equivalent :

1. $\exists x \in X, \forall y\in X, \exists g \in G \, \mid \, g\star x = y$
2. $\forall y\in X \implies y\in \mathcal{O}_x$

> A group action is called transitive if there is a single orbit i.e
> $\exists x\in X$ such that $\mathcal{O}_x=X$

So from this equivalent (standard) definition it's clear that more than one orbit means non transitive action.

Examples:

**Transitive action**:  Consider the group action of   $G=\{r_{120},r_{240},r_{360}=e\}$ (the group of rotational symmetries of an equilateral triangle ABC) on the set $X=\{A,B,C\}$ (all vertices of ABC) is a transitive action. (action is the rotation of vertices. For an example $r_{120} \star A=B$, $r_{240}\star B=A$).

**Nontransitive action**: Let $G=S_3$ and consider the action of $G$ on itself by conjugation i.e $(\pi, \sigma) =\pi \sigma \pi^{-1}$

Then
$\mathcal{O}_{(1) }=\{(1)\}$
$\mathcal{O}_{(12) }=\{(12),(13),(23)\}$

$\mathcal{O}_{(123) }=\{(123),(132)\}$

There is more than one orbit!

Now verify nontransitivity by $1$.