# Show that a Modified-group action, is also a group action.

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

Let $G$ be a group and $X$ a set. Define a modified-action as for which identity may not hold.

Have a subset $Y$ of the set $ X$ where holds:$\,e\star x\mid x.$

Can it be assumed that $e\star y$ has identity, as $e\star x= y, \implies e\star(e\star x) = e\star x$ doesn't help.
Unless that is possible, how to progress?

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: $e \star (e \star x) = e \star x$ is precisely $e \star y = y$ since $y = e \star x$. How does it not help?

Comment: @Zerox So, can show $Y$ is closed under pseudo group action, by showing that associativity holds, and closure is there too. For the purpose of showing associative property, need use the $(gh)\star x=g\star(h\star x)\tag{*}.$ However, for closure what need be shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For closure,  you need that given $e\star x\in Y$, that $g\star(e\star x)=e\star y$ for some $y\in G$.

So, let $y=g\star x$.  Then $g\star (e\star x)=(ge)\star x=g\star x=(eg)\star x=e\star (g\star x)=e\star y$.

Comment: But, how the assumption $y=g\star x$ was taken?

Comment: You need that $g\star y\in Y$ for each $y\in Y$.  It was easy to see using the associativity that $g\star x$ would work.